# Difference of nullptr

Tags: c++11

I would like to know if the difference of "2 concrete nullptr" of the same type is guaranteed to be equal to 0. I can't find anything in the C++ standard that guarantees that.

```
template <typename T>
std::ptrdiff_t diff() {
    T* p = nullptr;
    T* q = nullptr;
    return p - q;
}
```

In other words, does this code "has" to return 0?

The reason I am asking this question is that I want to implement my own vector class with

```
template <typename T>
class Vector {
private:
    T* data_;
    T* size_;
public:
    int size() const {
        return static_cast<int>(size_ - data_);
    }
}
```

and I am wondering if it is allowed to put data_ = size_ = nullptr when I construct a vector of length 0.

Comment: @Mat: You are right. This is a duplicate. But the question has not been answered in the other thread

Comment: @Mat: I've misread the first thread and its quote to the standard. The question has been answered and the result is guaranteed to be 0. Thanks.

Comment: This is confusing. Why is `size` a `T*` and not a `size_t`?

Answer (score 0):

Just quote @hdv. No, it is not. nullptr is a literal of a special type std::nullptr_t, which is not an integer type. In fact, nullptr - nullptr is an error because no - operator is defined for that type. You need to convert nullptr to a concrete pointer type (like the question does) to make the subtraction work.

Comment: In my example, p and q are concrete pointer type.